# Why is my approach to solving $\frac{dy}{dx}=1+xy$ not working?

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve the differential equation $$\frac{dy}{dx}=1+xy$$

I used the substitution $y=v+x$ so we get
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dx}+1$$ So the equations turns out to
$$\frac{dv}{dx}+1=1+x(v+x)$$
$\implies$
$$\frac{dv}{dx}+(-x)v=x^2$$ whose Integrating factor is $e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}$

So the solution is
$$v \times e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}=\int x^2e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}dx+C$$

But i am unable to integrate the above integrand in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: The integral does not have an analytical solution, do you know what an error function is?

Comment: Yes i know thank you i got it now

Comment: Well the first equation itself was in the linear form where you could use the integrating factor method.

Comment: @AmanKushwaha ya i know, but just tried in a different way

Answer (score 2):

You can integrate the integrand if integrating over $]-\infty, \infty[$.

This is a classic Gaussian integral, which solves to
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^2 e^{-x^2/2}dx = 2\int_{0}^{\infty}x^2 e^{-x^2/2}dx = \sqrt{2 \pi}.
$$